# Improving Google Map API V2 (GWT wrapper)'s LatLngBounds.contains

Tags: google-maps, gwt, latitude-longitude

I am wondering if there are any way to increase the accuracy of Google's LatLngBound.contains function because what I have at the moment tends to miss a few points.
(Can't post image sorry)

What the program does is suppose to show is which markers are within a chosen region and show that region + markers within but the accuracy is a bit off some markers outside of the region is also displayed. I am wondering if anyone have any idea on how to make it more accurate.

Comment: What does your region look like? Is it an irregular polygon by any chance? LatLngBounds is always a rectangle, so if your region has any other shape than a rectangle you might need a different approach.

Comment: Yes they are irregular shapes. Should I be using ray casting to further confirm if a point is within a region?

Comment: I have no idea what ray casting is. What I would do is to sent both the polygon and the nearby points to the PostgreSQL/PostGIS  server in an AJAX call and take advantage of the built-in PostGIS geometry functions to do the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a polygon contains method like that in Mike Williams' epoly extension, not LatLngBounds.contains (which as Marcelo says, will always be a rectangle).

[epoly](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm)